# Microsoft Office Interop Excel doesn't save in Windows server 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, office-interop

I am using Microsoft Office Excel Interop to create an excel file in ASP.NET C#. Everything is successful when I am running application in Visual Studio 2010. I have published my web application in my own IIS server, it is ok. But when I publish application in **Windows Server 2008**, the problem was detected.
I looked  for much in internet and i have done following, but the problem still was not solved:

1. I have set **Application Pool Identity** to **LocalSystem**. In Run -> mmc -32 -> Component Services -> My Computer -> DCOM Config -> Microsoft Excel Application -> right-click -> Properties window: in **Identity** tab, I have checked all radio buttons in this window.
2. I have set **Application Pool Identity** to **NetworkService**, and I have checked all previous radio buttons again.
3. In Run->mmc -32 -> Component Services -> My Computer -> DCOM Config -> Microsoft Excel Application -> right-click -> Properties window: in **Security** tab: I gave **Local Launch** and **Local Activation** for **INTERACTIVE, NETWORK SERVICE, IIS_IUSRS** users.

   Here is my code which I used *Interop Excel*:

> ```
> Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
> object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
>
> Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
> Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
>   
> Workbook.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("DownloadFolder\\" + fileName + "_siyahi.xls"));
> ```

Comment: There are a couple of places there that could throw an error in a web app.  Which line is it that gives the exception, and can you post the exception?  Also, have you checked that the account the app is running as has the proper file permissions to write to the folder / file?

Comment: I have **full control** permission to written folder for **iis_iusrs, myCmputer\\users** users. When I set **NetworkService** identity to Application pool then following error occurs "Microsoft Excel cannot open or save any more documents because there is not enough available memory or disk space".

Comment: You might want to read [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757#appliesto) about problems with Interop and ASP.NET. Quote: "Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem. In my Windows Server  **system regional settings** haven't been United States and I have set **worksheet.cells.NumberForm="0.00"** in my code.

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowNumber, 4].NumberFormat = "0.00";
```

Server doesn't knows this **number format**. I have changed **Format** to **English (United States)** and **Current location** to **United States** and my problem solved.